# How to resize jpg file by PHP?

Tags: php, resize, jpeg

It's now 925*1139,I want to change it to 90*110.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-resizeimage.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the [`imagecopyresampled`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) PHP function or the [`imagecopyresized`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function from the [GD library](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: The first one, as its name indicates, resampled while resizing for a better result. The second one only resize.

Answer (score 4):

Basically using GD is pretty easy once you know what to do.

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);        
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile); 

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600); 

$filename = '/path/to/images/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 600, $width, $height); 
imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);
```

Again check the blog for details.

Answer (score 0):

here's a resizing class called SimpleImage that you can use. Or take a look at the source and see how they tackle the problem:

[SimpleImage Code](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done PHP in a while (why am I even in this tag?) but you should check out GDLib. iirc, its better integrated than imagemagick.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php